Create Toggle to disable/enable class site wide?
I am trying to create a toggle that disables one class connected to a  tag similar to the theme toggle I already have. Turning it off would disable the colored text for easier reading (I like it, others might not). How would I go about doing this?
HTML CODE:
  <nav id="theme-options">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="galaxy.html">Theme Options</a>
          <div class="dropmenu_5col dropdown-fix1">
            <ul>
              <li>
                  <label id="switch" class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleTheme()" id="slider">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <label id="switch-color" class="switch-color">
                    <input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleTxtClr()" id="slider-color">
                    <span class="slider-color round"></span>
                </label>
              </li>      
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>    
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

SPAN EXAMPLE
<span class="color">green</span>

COLOR CHANGING SCRIPT
This will change the color depeneding on what is in the span tag only if the span tag has 'class="color"'. So I would need to remove or disable this with the toggle.
$('span.color').each(function() {
if( $(this).text() === 'green' || $(this).text() === 'greened' ){
$(this).css('color', '#008000')
}
})

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!
I have tried searching for scripts to do this (or something simular) and tried to get them to work with my limited JavaScript knowledge.

The easiest way would be to put a "tag" class on every element that you wanted to be able to change the color on and then use that to toggle the color class.  Something like this (the tag class is "foo"):


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.foo')].forEach( x => x.classList.add("green"));
  document.querySelector('#button').addEventListener('click', 
    (target) => [...document.querySelectorAll('.foo')].forEach( x => x.classList.toggle("green")))
})
.green {
  color: green;
}
<span class="foo">foo</span>
<span class="bar">bar</span>
<span class="foo">foo</span>
<br />
<button id='button'>&nbsp;</button>




I actually got this to work! Just need to beat it into submission for the gradient ones! Thank you! (I got busy and could not test it until now. lol)

I think using css variables will be more appropriate for handling something similar to darkmode.
They are simple to use too, create some variables in :root like --font_color & --background_color then add those variable wherever you wish like background-color: var(--background_color);.
Then you can directly manipulate variable values using js. Best thing is just my changing variable value at one place it will replace properties to all elements where that variable is used.
I have illustrated in below code do check it out. Thanks.


let darkmode = "off";
function toggleDarkMode(){
  var root = document.querySelector(':root');
  
  if(darkmode == "off"){
    root.style.setProperty('--font_color', "white");
    root.style.setProperty('--background_color', "black");
    darkmode = "on";
  }
  else{
    root.style.setProperty('--font_color', "black");
    root.style.setProperty('--background_color', "white");
    darkmode = "off";
  }
}
:root{
  --font_color: black;
  --background_color: white;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /*  Colors  */
  background-color: var(--background_color);
  color: var(--font_color);
}

button{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: var(--font_color);
}
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h2>This is sample text.</h2>
<button onclick="toggleDarkMode()">Toggle DarkMode</button>




Wasn't aware of CSS variables, thanks for the answer.  Two questions: 1) Could you use another CSS variable instead of the local darkmode variable?  2) Where are these variables scoped (are they scoped to the session, document, or something else)

Thank you so much for your input . 1) You can define any css properties inside a variable including font-size, file-path, display etc. also you can name them anything . 2) Once variables are defined they can we used within entire document. I hope this solves your quarries, you can know more here link.

I use variables for everything but this, and I do get what you're saying. However, I have A LOT more colors than just green so variables would not work. The only way I can see this working is to replace the class with a different class that the javascript for color is not using. How that script works is if the span contains 'gold' it will use the code for gold. Green uses green, red uses red. I also would want it to stay like it does for the dark/light theme if you changes pages (which uses local storage stuff somehow). I am sorry if I'm not making sense.

@CynthiaJohnson it really seems like you're missing the point of CSS.  Color is a style, you should be leveraging CSS to modify it.  You don't "disable" classes, you just remove them from the element.

Yes, I am aware. However, I am using a javascript to set the color so that I don't have to do it manually for thousands of instances. I have colorhere in my HTML. The script finds 'colorhere' and assigns a 'color=HexCode' to that span. What I was hoping for was a way to allow a user to toggle off the 'color' class so that it no longer displays the hexcode and uses the pages default text (which is using variables). So either I need to have a code that removes 'color' from any span that has 'color', or change it to a different class. Does that make more sense?

@CynthiaJohnson you're really not getting it.  You're re-inventing CSS.  Instead of having a script to change the color of the span, use CCS to do it.  You already have the class on the span, you don't need the script.
